# comment_reply_link() not showing up

Tags: comments

In `functions.php` I enqueue comment-reply and also define a callback function for use with `wp_list_comments()`:

```
function theme_queue_js(){
    if ( 
              ! is_admin() 
           && is_singular() 
           && comments_open() 
           && get_option('thread_comments') 
    )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'theme_queue_js');


function simple_comment_format($comment, $args, $depth) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
    <?php if ( $comment->comment_approved == '1'): ?>
    <li <?php comment_class(); ?>>
        <article>
            <time><?php comment_date(); ?></time>
            <h4><?php comment_author(); ?></h4>
            <?php comment_text(); ?>
            <?php comment_reply_link(); ?>
        </article>
    <?php endif;
}
```

And in `comments.php` I've kept things pretty minimal:

```
<section id="comment-form">
  <?php comment_form() ?>
</section>

<?php if ( have_comments() ): ?>
    <section class="commentlist">
        <h2>Comments!</h2>
        <ul>
            <?php   
                wp_list_comments( 
                    'type=comment&max_depth=5&callback=simple_comment_format'
                ); 
            ?>
        </ul>
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Everything is working ok except that the comment reply links are not showing up for any of the comments. 
The documentation on modifying comments in general seems really bad!
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try to replace

```
<?php comment_reply_link(); ?>
```

with:

```
<?php comment_reply_link( $args ); ?>
```

and to make sure the `$args['depth']` is not zero or greater or equal than the `$args['max depth']`. There will be [no output](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/64fb1a9e901d0776c2edebd5a651ff89fffe3a4c/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1582) if that's not the case.

If that doesn't work, you could try to add the comment ID or the comment object as the second input parameter to `comment_reply_link( $args, $comment )`.

Also check if the comments are *open*.

**Update:**

If we look at the [default callback](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/64fb1a9e901d0776c2edebd5a651ff89fffe3a4c/wp-includes/class-walker-comment.php#L292-299), we see how the arguments of  `comment_reply_link()` are constructed:

```
comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array(
    'add_below' => $add_below,
    'depth'     => $depth,
    'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'],
    'before'    => '<div class="reply">',
    'after'     => '</div>'
 ) ) );
```

where we can see how the `depth` and `max_depth` are included.

Comment: <?php comment_reply_link( $args ); ?> and comment_reply_link( $args, $comment ) didn't work for me. Comments are open. Is zero the default depth? In the discussion settings I have set  "Enable threaded (nested) comments" to 5 levels deep. What do I need to do to make sure the depth is not zero?

Comment: If you call `comment_reply_link()` without any arguments the default of depth is 0. Try eg.  `$args['depth'] = 1;` above it to test if it shows up then. @olliew

Comment: I updated the answer with an example from the default callback, where we can see how the depth is included @olliew